# Possessive reflexive pronouns (himself's, herself's, myself's, etc.)

Tags: list-of-languages, pronouns, possession, reflexive

"He looked out the window and saw his car."

Does "his" mean the same person initially called "he", or someone else? In English, it could be either one.

If the English language had the word "himself's", then that sentence would mean the car belonging to someone other than the person initially called "he". If it referred to the one initally called "he", it would say "He saw himself's car."

Which languages have such possessive reflexive pronouns?

Comment: Would you count *his own*?

Comment: [_Svoj_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/svoj%D1%8C#Descendants) in Slavic languages.

Comment: Mandarin has _ziji_ 'self' as a possessive reflexive pronoun. _He saw ziji DE car_.

Comment: Cannot you use the word *own* for this? 

"He looked out the window and saw own car." Looks awkward but I think it's grammatical.

Comment: It would be "his own", not just "own"

Comment: English **does** have _himself’s_ and _herself’s_, just not in this particular sense. _Himself_ and _herself_ are commonly used in Ireland to refer to your husband/wife or to someone who is (or thinks they are) quite hoity-toity, and in those senses it can take a possessive just fine; e.g., “Himself’s brother’s coming over tomorrow” (= my husband’s brother).

Answer (score 2):

Swedish is one such language that distinguishes these two meanings.

Here are the main personal and possessive pronouns. (I've left out spelling and dialect variants.)

```
         Subject            Object             Possessive, Common Possessive, Neuter Possessive, Plural  
______________________________________________________________________________________________________
1S       jag                mig                min                mitt               mina
         -                  mig (själv)        min (egen)         mitt (eget)        mina (egna)  
______________________________________________________________________________________________________
2S       du                 dig                din                ditt               dina
         -                  dig (själv)        din (egen)         ditt (eget)        dina (egna)
______________________________________________________________________________________________________
3S.FEM   hon                henne              hennes             hennes             hennes
         -                  sig (själv)        sin (egen)         sitt (eget)        sina (egna)

3S.MASC  han                honom              hans               hans               hans
         -                  sig (själv)        sin (egen)         sitt (eget)        sina (egna)

3S.EPI   hen                hen                hens               hens               hens
         -                  sig (själv)        sin (egen)         sitt (eget)        sina (egna)
           
3S.C     den                den                dens               dens               dens
         -                  sig (själv)        sin (egen)         sitt (eget)        sina (egna)

3S.N     det                det                dess               dess               dess
         -                  sig (självt)       sin (egen)         sitt (eget)        sina (egna)
______________________________________________________________________________________________________
1P       vi                 oss                vår                vårt               våra
         -                  oss (själva)       vår (egen)         vårt (eget)        våra (egna)
______________________________________________________________________________________________________
2P       ni                 er                 er                 ert                era
         -                  er (själva)        er (egen)          ert (eget)         era (egna)
______________________________________________________________________________________________________
3P       de                 dem                deras              deras              deras
         -                  dem (själva)       sin (egen)         sitt (eget)        sina (egna)
```

I've put the reflexives on the line below. *Själv/-t/-a* and *egen/eget/egna* are used for emphasis, but if you ignore those, you'll see that the differentiation is only in third person, with *sig* as the object pronoun and *sin/sitt/sina* as the possessive. Third-person non-reflexive possessives end with "s" and do not change for the gender or number of the possessum, unlike all the other possessive pronouns.

*Han såg* ***hans*** *bil.* "He saw his car." ( = another man's car)
*Han såg* ***sin (egen)*** *bil*. "He saw his (own) car."